# Samsung 830 very slow benchmark numbers

Tags: ssd

I just bought a new SSD, and installed a fresh copy of Windows on it. I didn't see any noticeable difference in boot times, app start-up times, so I decided to benchmark it.

- Asus P7P55D-E
- Intel i5-760
- **Samsung 830 256GB SATA III**
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

The Windows experience index gave the drive a 7.3 rating, but real-world performance is not particularly impressive.

[image: ATTO]
[image: AS SSD]
[image: Samsung SSD Magician]

Any ideas why the numbers are so low?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that SATA III support is turned off by default on the P7P55D motherboard. After enabling it in BIOS (Tools -> Level Up), the scores went up:

```
      Read  Write
Seq   325   183
4K    16    49
IOPS  32K   28K
```

It's an improvement, but still far below what they should be for this drive.

Comment: What is low about these numbers? Doing random 4K IOps on a 15K RPM SAS drive yield speeds in the single digit MB/sec.  Your drive benchmarks those at 12MB/sec. A order of magnitude faster.  (Ignore the sequential stuff).

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-7PC256D/AM-specs. Go check the advertised specs for this drive. There are plenty of reviews and benchmarks that back up those numbers. And why are you comparing an SSD to a HDD?

Comment: Yes, the SATA bus in AHCI mode. And the mobo supports SATA III (though these numbers are kind of slow even for SATA II).

Comment: @alekop Yeah I just noticed in the screenshot you're using msachi. I agree your numbers are low for that drive, the WEI is too.

Comment: How is the partition aligned?

Comment: Strange. According to SysInfo, the drive actually has two partitions (I didn't do it myself, only drive C: is visible). The first one has an offset of 105,906,176. There is no information about the second. However, in the AS SSD screenshot above it says `103424 OK`.

Comment: 105,906,176 bytes is the same as 103,424KB or 101 MB.  That should be fine since it is a multiple of whole megabytes.  As for the first partition, that could be windows boot/bitlocker.

Comment: @alekop Are you sure you're not using a SATA II port?